# Installing 'cvxpy' in Python 3.7 virtenv and receiving 'No module' errror

Tags: python, pip, cvxpy

I've created a virtual environment via Anaconda to run Python 3.7.0 and install 'cvxpy'.  However, as you can see in the code and associated error, even though it appears to be installed, I am not able to import the module.

```
!pip install cvxpy
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: for cvxpy, ecos, osqp, scipy, numpy, scs, future
```

```
import cvxpy as cp
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b9466877789b> in <module>
----> 1 import cvxpy as cp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvxpy'
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Did the installation run successfully?

Comment: try: `!conda install cvxpy`

Comment: When running !conda install I get this error:                                 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cvxpy

Comment: was a solution found?

Comment: Try running `conda activate cvxpy_env` before running, say, `python3 helloworld.py`